# FFMPEG for Android does not work properly when overlaying picture

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Whenever I run this FFMPEG command on Android to overlay a picture on a video using the [FFMpeg Android library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android):

```
 "-i",
                realPathVideo,
                "-i",
                realPathImage
                ,
                "-filter_complex",
                "overlay=0:0",
                "-codec:a",
                "copy",
                dest.getAbsolutePath()
```

it never actually works, since it always ends up in "onFinish
" and never "onSuccess". I don't know why, but somehow this command doesn't work properly, although it never shows me an error message. To ensure that the parameters are right I will show you how I get them:

realpathvideo is: `/storage/emulated/0video.mp4`
realpathimage is: `/storage/emulated/0/VideoOverlay.jpg`
output directory is: `/storage/emulated/0/appname/temporaryVideoFileWithOverlay.mp4`

realPathVideo is derived from a File which is made by moving the result of a camera activity to external storage with the method:

```
public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException
{
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try
    {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

where src is the video result saved in internal storage and dst the external storage file.

The bitmap image overlay File is saved like this:

realpathImage is derived from a bitmap File saved by using:

```
    private Uri saveOverlay(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File file;
    // Get the external storage directory path
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    // Create a file to save the image
    file = new File(path, "VideoOverlay" + ".jpg");

    try {

        OutputStream stream = null;

        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        stream.flush();


        stream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse the saved image path to uri
    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return savedImageURI;
}
```

Comment: Add the `-report` option to the ffmpeg command. Then look for a file such as `ffmpeg-20200313-085020.log` in the working directory. View bottom of log for any errors. If it does not exist it indicates that ffmpeg likely did not execute.

Comment: where excactly can I find that working directory?

Comment: I know nothing of Android, but look in the directory that the script is executed from. If that fails just do a search for `ffmpeg-*.log`

Comment: I searched in my Android Studio for the file "ffmpeg-*.log" but could not find any results, maybe the log files are dumped on the device, but I don't think I will be succesfull in finding them

Comment: It may indicate that your script failed before ffmpeg was executed, so therefore no log was created.

Comment: yes, but judging from the syntax and appropiate intput given to the command, why did it not work in the first place? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No. Without any error messages or the log/report/stderr output from ffmpeg I can suggest nothing.